# Is it possible to reference another column to create a 'combinatorial' query?

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, recursive-query

Lets say I have a table with these columns:

```
| id | mass | sequence | A | M | C |
  0    100    AMMA       2   2   0
  1    200    MMMC       1   3   1
```

I am interested in querying for the mass "220". Of course, none of these entries will register as a hit because they 100 =/= 220 and 200 =/= 220.

But I want to account for the possibility that each 'M' in the string can add '10' to the mass value, so for the first entry, I want it to also register for the masses 110, 120. For the second entry, I want it to register for the masses 210, 220, 230.

Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE mass IN (mass, mass + M*10);
```

This query is not sufficient because it only accounts for the case where all M's add 10. I want to account for every M either adding or not adding 10.

I should note that the matches must be very precise (within an error window of 1). So 225 should not register as a hit, only:

```
209 < x < 211
219 < x < 221
229 < x < 231
```

Is this possible with a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
where 220 between mass and mass + m * 10
```

You could also phrase this as:

```
where 220 - mass between 0 and m * 10
```

If you want an exact match, a recursive query is an alternative (this requires MySQL 8.0):

```
with cte as (
    select id, mass, m from mytable
    union all
    select id, mass, m - 1 from cte where m > 0
)
select * from cte where mass + m * 10 = 220
```

If you want to allow a tolerance of `1`, then just change the final query:

```
with cte as (...)
select * from cte where mass + m * 10 - 220 between -1 and 1
```

Comment: Unforuntately no, the match must be very exact (within an error window of ~1). So I wouldn't want 225 to register as a hit. Only 200, 210, 220, 230. I updated my question -- thanks for pointing that out

Comment: I think this is what I need. I will accept your answer! I'm a big MySQL noob so this hurts my head to look at, so I'll need to do some reading into this. Is there any chance you could explain how that recursive 'common table expression' works? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive

Comment: @Vranvs: the first query in the CTE selects all rows from the table. Then, the recursive part (after `union all`) generates new rows where `m` is incrementally decreased, until it reaches `0`.

Comment: I think I understand. This actually doesn't solve my EXACT problem but its okay! This puts me on the right track to understanding what I need to do. Thank you!!

Comment: @Vranvs: I edited to show how to set +/-1 tolerance.